# React Navigation: Navigate into page, increase RAM, navigate back and RAM stays high

Tags: react-native, memory-management, expo, react-navigation

I'm having issues in my app where I navigate to a page, the RAM usage increases, then I navigate back, expecting the memory consumption to go back down, but the RAM usage stays high.

Here is a repo where I provide a reproducible example:
https://github.com/spagrhetti/performance-debugging

The basic setup is this:

1. My app has two screens, screen A and screen B, both screens in a React Navigation Stack Navigator. We start on screen A.
2. Navigate to screen B. Screen B has a button that adds a giant string to a useState array. Do this however much you want, after 2 presses RAM usage goes up from ~100MB to about ~850MB on my device (iphone 12 mini).
3. Navigate back to screen A. I would expect memory to go back down, but it stays at that ~850MB level.

Additionally, here is a video of the test: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ubiYwzrlaQw

Am I missing something? Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior of having RAM go down after navigating back?

I've asked chatGPT about this and it basically tells me that garbage collection in javascript is hard to predict and maybe somehow that memory will get freed later. However, I think that variations of this behavior are causing my app to steadily use more and more RAM as I navigate around, eventually causing it to crash.

Any help on understanding why this occurs and how to better handle memory when dealing with React Navigation would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I notice similar behavior without any navigation involved: allocating a big state var, then setting it to null, RAM usage stays high. I don't completely understand this -- my guess is that I just have to wait for garbage collection to kick in and eventually bring RAM usage back down. However, in my app, that never seems to happen, it just keeps going up and eventually it crashes.

Comment: It will crash, of course, I think JS garbage collection works on large intervals of 5-10 mins, but from the video, your JS thread and your UI thread are doing great, what do you mean by 'giant string'?  In my opinion, doing react-native apps in the past 8 years, it is not native, and it will never be (I'm not saying that the technology sucks, I'll always use react-native) if you have a heavy process task consider tackling it on a different way or directly on the native side, if you describe your use-case would be more helpful

Comment: @ko100v.d The giant string is defined like this:

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const largeString = new Array(100000000).join("A"); 
    setData((p) => [...p, largeString]);
  };
```

I just did this to simulate a heavy memory consumption task. In my actual app, I'm doing things like scrolling through images and videos (In the repo provided, I also have a "PageB" that mimics this use case better, and I still see the exact behavior that I see here. 

So since I can't force garbage collection, is the idea that I just have to stay below crashing RAM levels for 5-10 minutes?